# how to simplify this function in terms of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$y=\frac{3x}{x^{2}+1}$

and I want to obtain x in terms of y, so far what I have done is the following:

$3x=y(x^{2}+1)$

$3x=x^{2}y+y$

$3x-x^{2}y=y$

and at this point I got stucked, because that cuadratic term would not allow me to just get one x in one side of the equation. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: you have a polynomial of degree 2 in $x$. Apply quadratic formula and you will get 2 values for $x$.

Comment: It is not possible to express $x$ as a function of $y$ because the given function is not injective.

Comment: thank you @user376343, is that because the square term appears in x, so that a positive and a negative number could me mapped to the same y?

Comment: $x^2(-y) + x(3) + (-y) = 0$.  This is a quadratic equation in $x$, of form $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$, where $A = -y, B = 3, C = -y$.  Simply apply the formula $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{2A} \times \left[ -B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}\right].$  This will yield (potentially) $2$ **candidate specifications for $x$ in terms of $y$.  You must then manually check each candidate specification against the original expression of $y$ in terms of $x$, to determine which candidate specification(s) (if any) satisfy the original expression.

Comment: @Lila I added an answer not a comment, because the graph helps (I do not know to enclose a picture in the comment).

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x)=\frac{3x}{x^2+1}.$ For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ Therefore, the function is odd and there is no difficulty due to positive or negative values of $x.$ But the function is not injective, as can be seen on its graph
[image]
The function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}.$ With the help of analysis we can verify that $f(-1)=-3/2$ is a minimum, $f(1)=3/2$ a maximum, the limits at $\pm \infty$ are zero, and each value $y\neq 0$, $y\in (-3/2, 3/2)$ is obtained for two different values $x_1, x_2.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you think that I can safely said that the function is not injective also because of the presence of the x^2 term?

Comment: No. As a counterexample: $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x$ is injective, but has $x^2$ in its expression.

Answer (score 1):

From the last equation, you get $$x^2y -3x +y=0$$ and using quadratic equation, while treating $x$ as the variable, and the $y$ terms as coefficients, you get $$x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{ 9 - 4y^2}}{2y}$$ if $y\neq 0$. (In $y=0$ case also, we can easily get that $x=0$.)

Also, note that strictly speaking, this is not a function as $x$ can attain two different values for the same $y$, but this does give a way to compute $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case I think that this function pass the vertical line test or am I wrong? I think that is not one-to-one.